# Moving text line

Tags: html

I want to create a moving text line. Can anybody help me, how can I specify that. For example, I want `<h1> Hi User</h1>` this text line to continuously move from left to right corner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `<marquee>` for this.

```
<marquee direction="right"><h4>Hi user</h4></marquee>
```

Note that it's *deprecated* in HTML4.01.

Comment: I use this. However, showing error Unkwon tag <marquee >.Any other solution ?

Comment: Ignore and run it. Browsers are more forgiving than IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

You can [use the `marquee` tag for that](http://www.mountaindragon.com/html/marquee.htm).

Other possibility will be using JQuery to do some animations to your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

`<marquee>` tag is used in html for moving text line

Hi this is moving text "

this will a simple create a moving line.
Now you can customize this like its movement, background color, text color, scroll with mouse and much more.
Now read this text.

```
<marquee bgcolor="#33cc99" style="color:white;width:500px;" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()""><br /> <b>
<a href="http://uhackhere.blogspot.com"> This Link is shared from uhack blog</a> </b> <br />
</marquee>"
```

This is an example of moving text, which will move right to left , having background a background color and stop when mouse pointed on it.